# how to pre-load data upon application startup in an OWIN self-hosted applicatgion

Tags: entity-framework, owin, self-host-webapi

I have a need to pre-load some Entity Framework data upon application start up in my OWIN / TopShelf self-hosted application.
What is the technique for initializing the EF DbContext, and pulling up data, as this self=hosted app starts up?
Should this be done in the Startup.cs file or elsewhere?